Connecting to SQL Server from ASP.NET
I created a SQL Server database on my computer, I use SQL Server Management Studio to manage the database.
I then added a login, selected SQL Server authentication for that login. I can connect to the database using this login and password through SSMS, but I can't do it in ASP.NET.
I use a connection string like this:
Server=serverName;Database=databaseName;User Id=userName;Password=password;

I'm sure everything is fine in the code, the problem must be either in the wrong connection string or in the wrong database configuration.
Does anyone have any ideas? I take the data for the connection string from SSMS from connection properties. I am connecting from the same computer.
This is the code that is supposed to connect to the database:
  public class DatabaseService
{
    private readonly string _connectionString = ...;

    public IEnumerable<Country> GetCountries()
    {
        using var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        
        using var cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, CountryName FROM Countries";
        
        var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        var countries = new List<Country>();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            var country = new Country()
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]),
                Name = dr["CountryName"].ToString()
            };
            countries.Add(country);
        }
        
        connection.Close();
        return countries;
    }
}



[Route("api/countries")]
[ApiController]
public class CountriesController : ControllerBase
{
    private DatabaseService _dbService;

    public CountriesController()
    {
        _dbService = new DatabaseService();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetCountry()
    {
        IEnumerable<Country> countries = _dbService.GetCountries();

        return Ok(countries);
    }
}

 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error.

Database has SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode enabled

Please provide more details.  The full section of code in your .net app that is connecting and trying to execute something and what the actual error messages are along with the full connection string (minus the sensitive data).

Presumably you have new SqlConnection(yourString) and .Open() - what happens when you call .Open()? is there an exception? what does it say exactly?

"SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" turned on under Server Properties->Security? Please provide the code for better understanding.

It has SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode

Try this syntaxes of the connection string Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDb;User ID=user;password=password123;persist security info=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;. Also make sure the user has access to the db.

Solution:
<InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization> => <InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>

I only saw this after using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient instead of System.Data.SqlClient because it displays the error message in a readable way.

Maybe your password have some special characters like semicolon?
If not - try to output entire exception information, now it is not sufficient information to answer.
